# How to render array of object in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get list of users using `reactJS 15.5`, Code:

```
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
        this.state = {
            values: []
        };
        this.getDataFromUser = this.getDataFromUser.bind(this);
    }

 render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.getDataFromUser}>Fetch</button>
                <p>
                    {this.state.values}
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }

 getDataFromUser(){
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/user')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                console.log(json);
                this.setState({values: json })
        })
    }
```

In `console.log(json)`, i get [image]

But i get this error when i click in button **Fetch** so error in getDataFromUser:

> Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation): Objects are not valid as a
>   React child (found: object with keys {id, nom, prenom,
>   email,is_admin,created_at, updated_at}). If you meant to render a
>   collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using
>   createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.

There's a why to create user object, So anyone can help me to resolve this issue and thanks

Comment: Show the JSON response and if you are getting array of user use that to display inside some markup.

Comment: I guess you need to loop over this.state.values.

Comment: @JaromandaX i get error when i click in Fetch button

Comment: @Akram can you show the result of `console.log(json);` ?

Comment: @MayankShukla i added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its an **array of objects** so you need to use `map` to iterate the array then render the specific values.

Like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.getDataFromUser}>Fetch</button>
            <p>
                {this.state.values.map(el => {
                    return <div key={el.id}>
                       <span>{el.email}</span>
                       <span>{el.nom}</span>
                       <span>{el.is_manager}</span>
                    </div>
                })}
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: i am a newbie to react, i want to ask you if this best way to get and parse json ? and it possible to create user with nom, id ..., and use in all component and thanks

Comment: both the libs are good, but they handle the things differently. check this link for difference and benefits of axios and fetch call: https://medium.com/@shahata/why-i-wont-be-using-fetch-api-in-my-apps-6900e6c6fe78

Comment: if the data that you are fetching is fixed means not dependent on any user input then you can make this call inside componentDidMount method directly instead of making that on button click. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return an invalid object/array in your react component. In your case you should try and iterate through the array(this.state.values) and render the items(string values) needed.

```
 render() {
    const { values } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.getDataFromUser}>Fetch</button>
            <p>
                {values.map((value, index) => 
                    (<div key={index}>{value.nom}</div>)
                )}
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Looking at the error it looks like the new state of this.state.values is rather an object with the following keys {id, nom, prenom, email,is_admin,created_at, updated_at}. So the below code would work for u.

```
render() {
    const { values } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.getDataFromUser}>Fetch</button>
            <p>
                {values &&
                  <div>
                    {values.nom}
                    {values.prenom}
                    {values.email}
                    etc.
                  </div>
                }
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: @collison thank you to answer to this question, but not working for me

Comment: to make the second code work in your constructor, remove this.state = {
            values: []
        };

Comment: i get array of object [OBJECT,OBJECT,OBJECT...] in each object i have nom, email ....

Comment: Then you'd need to use the first code if you are returning an array. And retain this.state = { values: [] } in your constructor.

Comment: made changes to the first code please refer. And let me know

Comment: @Akram please upvote if this is right or let me know if there are any more issues

Comment: yes @collison it not work for me i try this before i post question, i don't know why not work

Comment: Which of the above codes are u using please. Can u share.

Comment: i use  {values.map((value, index) => 
                   (<div key={index}>{value.nom}</div>)
                )}